# "Where have you been?" or "Where had you been?"

Tags: tenses

Which usage is correct?

> Where have you been?
>
> Where had you been?

Can we ask *Where had you been* as a past tense? Can I answer *I had been* which happened in the past?

Is the rhyme

> Pussy cat, Pussy cat, Where have you been?
>
> I have been to London to look at the queen

proper? Please elaborate.

Comment: The rhyme is: *Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been; I've been up to London to visit the Queen; Pussy cat, pussy cat, what did you there?; I frightened a little mouse under a chair*.

Answer (score 5):

Both "Where have you been?" and "Where had you been?" are grammatically correct.  The only difference is the tense.

"Where have you been?" is present perfect, and is used to convey a sense of a time immediately before the present.  In this case, the person we are asking likely just showed up, and we're asking them where they just came from.

"Where had you been?" is past perfect, and is used to convey a sense of a completed action in the past.  In this case, the person we are asking was absent for some event in the past, and we are asking them where they were during that event.